# Spring beans throw exception when starting the server

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am working on a project that is (I'd like to say "randomly", since it sometimes starts and after a restart of the server it throws exception apparently with no reason) giving problems about the bean conversion service.

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'project.formatter.DateFormatter#3636796b' of type [project.formatter.DateFormatter] while setting bean property 'formatters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [project.formatter.DateFormatter] for bean with name 'project.formatter.DateFormatter#3636796b' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.formatter.DateFormatter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedSet(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:394)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:818)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4772)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [project.formatter.DateFormatter] for bean with name 'project.formatter.DateFormatter#3636796b' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.formatter.DateFormatter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.formatter.DateFormatter
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1343)
... 27 more
```

and then the exception on the servlet:

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'project.formatter.DateFormatter#3636796b' of type [project.formatter.DateFormatter] while setting bean property 'formatters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [project.formatter.DateFormatter] for bean with name 'project.formatter.DateFormatter#3636796b' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.formatter.DateFormatter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedSet(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:394)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:818)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4772)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [project.formatter.DateFormatter] for bean with name 'project.formatter.DateFormatter#3636796b' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.formatter.DateFormatter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.formatter.DateFormatter
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1343)
... 27 more

gen 20, 2017 10:05:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext list enerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'project.formatter.DateFormatter#3636796b' of type [project.formatter.DateFormatter] while setting bean property 'formatters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [project.formatter.DateFormatter] for bean with name 'project.formatter.DateFormatter#3636796b' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.formatter.DateFormatter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedSet(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:394)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:818)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4772)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [project.formatter.DateFormatter] for bean with name 'project.formatter.DateFormatter#3636796b' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.formatter.DateFormatter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.formatter.DateFormatter
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1343)
... 27 more

gen 20, 2017 10:05:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
gen 20, 2017 10:05:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Context [/ProjectWorkMaven] startup failed due to previous errors
```

It seems to not find the class, but the class is actually under `project.formatter.DateFormatter`

Here is the `spring-mvcconfig.xml` bean:

```
 <bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
     <property name="formatters">
        <set>
            <bean class="project.formatter.DateFormatter">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </bean>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here the `DateFormatter` class:

```
package project.formatter;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.format.Formatter;

public class DateFormatter implements Formatter<Date> {

private String datePattern;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

public DateFormatter(String datePattern) {
    this.datePattern = datePattern;
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
}


public String print(Date date, Locale locale) {
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}


public Date parse(String s, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    try {
        return dateFormat.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // the error message will be displayed when using <form:errors>
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "invalid date format. Please use this pattern\""
                        + datePattern + "\"");
    }
}
}
```

It gives the same error to other people who's working with me but they only need to do a `maven clean` to resolve the issue, for me is not working this method.
I do a clean, then restart the server and I got the same error, the only way is to re-do a checkout from the svn, it works for a while and then it starts to give me this problem again.
I am not working on that class, I neither edit the  `springmvc-config.xml`
I do not know how to look to solve this problem.
I checked the `springmvc-config`, the `web.xml`, where else should I look to try to fix this problem?
Thanks You all for the help.

EDIT:
It seems to give errors with every other bean. I commented the conversionService bean, it gives no more exception on that and throws exception on the bean dataSource, commented such that bean, it sends error on the spring-security beans. I don't think due to dependencies on such those beans, where should I lokk? It worked everything great up to two days ago, and no changes have been made on the configuration of the project, now I try to checkout the package on a VM.
EDIT2:
It doesn't work neither on the VM. I am not able to understand why such a problem. I also tried to delete the project and re-check it out, but it is not still working, same problem.
If any of you can suggest me how to look it would be great, not any other people in my team is having this problem.

Comment: Are you using hot deployment from eclipse?

Comment: @Setu No, I'm not using it. I am using just maven plugin, svn plugin and tomcat 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure Following.

1) `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean.java` must have property with name `formatters` of type `project.formatter.DateFormatter`.

2) Rebuild your project and then redeploy to the server.

Note: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` only occurs when there is no yourClass.class found by the server.

Comment: It does not work only on my machine, everything is setted. It worked up to yesterday with no problems. It seems to don't be able to load any bean.

Comment: Perform clean and build to the application then also clean your server cache.

Comment: I did it many times, it does not resolve the problem. I also tried to delete the project and re-check it out, same problem.It works for the other people when they get the problem, not for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved removing the resource from server, doing a clean on the server, then a clean on the project, I rebuilt it and redeployed it on the server. 
I can still not guess why all those problems.
Thanks for the help.